# What is the default retry policy mechanism OKHttp? (Android)

Tags: android, retrofit2, okhttp, retry-logic

I have been trying to find an answer for this one and could not find any.

There are many techniques where we can implement retry in OkHttp with retrofit and also configure it

As per the document https://square.github.io/okhttp/4.x/okhttp/okhttp3/-ok-http-client/-builder/retry-on-connection-failure/
fun retryOnConnectionFailure(retryOnConnectionFailure:Boolean): Builder

We can configure whether retry is required or not. And the default value is true.

But **what is the default retry mechanism in OkHttp**

How many times will the call be made?

What is the default exponential logic in OkHttp?

Can anyone help in this

Answer (score 8):

OkHttp will try to retry a request when the following is generally true

- The error is a connection error and there is alternative route (dns address, proxy etc) - https://square.github.io/okhttp/4.x/okhttp/okhttp3/-ok-http-client/-builder/retry-on-connection-failure/
- the request was attempted but the response indicates it is safe to retry and the request is repeatable. (408 responses - https://github.com/square/okhttp/pull/2302)

There is no advanced logic in OkHttp for this, if you need particular retry logic you can consider disabling any automatic retries and implementing exactly the strategy you need.

See also https://medium.com/inloopx/okhttp-is-quietly-retrying-requests-is-your-api-ready-19489ef35ace